# Is there any algorithm to find the kth smallest element in a max-heap in O(log n) time?

Tags: algorithm, heap, heapsort

In the worst case, the kth smallest element might be at the last level of the max-heap.In that case, time needed to find the element could go to O(n) since there may be n/2 elements in the worst case in the last level of the heap.
Or
Is there any other algorithm to find the kth smallest element in a MAX heap in O(logn) time ?

n = no. of elements in the heap

Comment: I think it depends on the representation of the tree. If each node stores the number of  leafs below it, you could use binary search to get O(log n). Also, see [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/k-th-greatest-element-in-a-max-heap/) for a related discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do this in O(k log n). To explain the procedure, consider an example array `[30,20,10,9,7,5]`.

The heap structure for this is given by:

[image: Max Heap]

Now, we have the following pattern.

- 1st min element -> 6th max element
- 2nd min element -> 5th max element
- 3rd min element -> 4th max element
- ..
- ..
- ..
- kth min element -> (n-k+1)th max element

For example, in our example 5th min element -> 2nd max element -> **20**

Comment: I think O(klogn) is definitely different from O(log n)

Comment: @BorisStrandjev Yes. Even to find the kth max element in a max-heap, it takes O(k log n). Also, when k is O(1), this is ~ O(log n) which is way better than O(n)

Comment: It's only O(log n) when k is O(1). k << n is not sufficient. But when k is O(1), finding the kth smallest element is O(1) because there are only O(2^k) places in the tree it can be.

Comment: There are solutions of finding kth element of O(log n) disrespective of k in [0.. n]. This is what O (log n) is and what the OP is asking

Comment: @SohamChatterjee Can you clarify on this `k` value?

Comment: We have standard algorithms to extract kth largest element in O(klog n) time. kth smallest element is (n-k+1)th largest element. So, we can extract n-k+1 elements from max-heap; that would give a time complexity of O((n-k) logn). What i want is that the smallest element is to be found in O(logn) time from the max heap.

Comment: @SohamChatterjee I don't think you can do better than this. Not sure, anyway. But this is better than O(n)